# does higher impression ctr give higher payment, do ads in view.gone state add to impression count

Tags: admob, payment

I've found it hard to determine how payment is calculated even in a general way after researching the admob docs and stack overflow. one basic question is whether a higher ctr rate means higher payment per click. I've decided not to show an ad all the time, as i'm getting so little for bothering my free game players constantly with a banner ad, and am deciding between two ways to clear and reshow the ad.

if I use adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and adView.setVisibility(View.GONE) to show and hide ad during play, i'm concerned the ad will still be counting toward my total impressions even while it's hidden. in that case I would have to destroy and recreate the adView object instead, although that would likely cause a hiccup during play each time I recreated the adView.

so two related questions: does higher ctr give higher payment per click, and does an adView in the view.gone state still download ads and add to your impression count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work it appears from the log that ads are not downloaded in the view.gone state.

I had to eliminate the the 'addtestdevice' flag in the main activity, and even then I only got a 'to get test ads on this device add testdevice...' message in the log, and no ads on the device after downloading the new code to the device from the laptop. I had to restart the app from the device a couple times to actually get real ads on it. In the view.visible state I got '...refreshed...' log messages every minute, filtering the hundreds of log messages with the the 'ads' tag. In the view.gone state I got no 'ads' messages at all. From this I'm assuming messages aren't even downloaded in the view.gone state so they won't count against your CTR.

I'm still waiting for this question to be posted on the admob forum, but I may have to resubmit it as two separate questions to get it approved to be posted if I want to pursue it, as it's been several days since I submitted it. Thanks to William for his response.

I couple weeks after I initially posted this I received this from admob support:

"Thanks for your patience.

CTR does not directly affect the CPC of ads in your apps. We use a variety of inputs to provide the best performing ad for each ad request.

As for your second question, yes.  If your application succeeds in an ad request, an ad will be served and the ad impression will be counted even if the ad is hidden.

Thanks,"

However, as mentioned before, in my own tests the ad was not refreshed when hidden.

Comment: You almost certainly didn't need to restart the app to get the ads. There is a 5 minute cache for the mediation list and if you had waited 5 mins it would have retrieved ads first time (assuming there were some available).

Answer (score 2):

> does higher ctr give higher payment per click

No. I suspect a higher CTR will give you access to better quality (and higher paying ads). But I suspect that most relevance is given to the number of requests you make, followed by the CTR. Advertisers are looking for eyeballs and how well those eyeballs translate into product purchases.

> does an adView in the view.gone state still download ads and add to
>   your impression count?

I don't believe so, I think it is likely to stop loading ads when GONE. You can verify that by looking at the logs. An alternate is to use adView#stopLoading when you want ads to stop and kick it off again by loading a new AdRequest. You don't need to destroy the AdView.

Comment: tks for responding, I'm still waiting for this to be posted on the admob developers forum, sometimes they just don't poste a question. i'm just starting out and my impressions vary from 20 to 100 day by day, so I won't be able to verify from the logs if downloading stops with view.gone unless I completely stop my ads for a day with view.gone at the beginning of the app, unless your referring to something else.

Comment: You can check this on a local device. Create a version using View.GONE and see whether new AdRequests are being sent when in that state.

Comment: do you mean check the log to see whether new ad requests are being sent? when in view.gone the ad doesn't show, it doesn't even create space for the ad, so i'm assuming i can't check if ads are being downloaded by observing the device. i'm using Surfaceview for my game so I had to create an extra view just for the adview. do you mean check to log to determine if the ad is being sent, filtering log messages with the 'ads' tag?

Comment: i'm experimenting with this now, although I've flagged my device as a "test device" in the code so it only gets test ads right now, and not showing anything about ad downloads in the log. it looks like i'll have to eliminate the test device flag so it shows real ads and work further with log observations.